# Rails4: don't raise ActionController::ParameterMissing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a generic form which posts to my `update` action, but sometimes without any single parameter sent out.

Which means the

```
params.require(:object).permit([
  :field1, :field2 # etc.
])
```

raises the `ActionController::ParameterMissing`.

But in my case, it is a normal case, I'd simply like to call `@object.update_attributes({})`.

What would be a clean way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply rescue from the `ActionController::ParameterMissing` error:

```
  begin
    params.require(:object).permit([:field1, :field2])
  rescue ActionController::ParameterMissing => e
    @object.update_attributes({})
  end
```

Comment: No chance this could be set at application level though?

Comment: Of course, you can use `rescue_from` in `ApplicationController`.